# Django FileField (or ImageField) open() method returns None for valid file?

Tags: python, django

let me put it like this:

model.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    seq_file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

ajax.py (I'm using dajaxice but it doesn't matter):

```
...
def startTask(request, name):
    task = Task.objects.get(task_name=name)
    data = task.seq_file.open()
    filename = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT ,task.seq_file.name)
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise Exception, "file " + filename + " not found."
    sequences = parser.parse(data.read())
    ...
```

this returns:

```
File "/home/mnowotka/Dokumenty/MgrFuncAdnot/app/django-gui/src/gui/ajax.py", line 43, in startTask
sequences = parser.parse(data.read())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

but:

```
...
def startTask(request, name):
    task = Task.objects.get(task_name=name)
    filename = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT ,task.seq_file.name)
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise Exception, "file " + filename + " not found."
    data = open(filename)  
    sequences = parser.parse(data.read())
    ...
```

works perfectly!
Why?

(I'm using django 1.3)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

because `open` method of `models.FileField` doesn't return anything

you can just use:

```
task.seq_file.read()
```

and you don't need calculate path of file for checking if file exist. you can use `task.seq_file.path`:

```
if not os.path.isfile(task.seq_file.path):
    ....
```

Comment: So what is the purpose of FileField open() ?

Comment: Unfortunately the Django documentation is currently misleading on this point: "Behaves like the standard Python open() method..." - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile

No, returning None after performing a mysterious internal open operation is not standard Python behaviour.

Comment: should raise an issue on this.

Comment: Wow, this (read/seq_file) seems to be amazingly undocumented. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I stumbled upon this recently and just submitted a ticket and potential improvement to the docs here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26508

Answer (score 15):

A [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) will give you a file-like object and there is no need to call open() on it. In your example, just call `task.seq_file.file`.

Why is that? There are many storage backends for `FileField`, and many of them are not backed by a file in disk (think of S3 storage, for example). I guess that is why the documentation says it returns a file-like object, not a file. For some kinds of storage the "open" method makes no sense.

Comment: But according to django documentation FileField is a file proxy and I can call open on that object. I didn't even get error about not defined method so it is there, right? So is it a bug or I just don't understand something?

Comment: @mnowotka: it is there, but I never used it, FileField will give you a file-like object (already "open").

Comment: keep in mind that a FileField is not necessarily backed by a file on disk (S3, other kinds of cloud storage)

Comment: @WenzelJakob: this is a good remark: for some kinds of storage, the "open" method makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, check the code. Here's an excerpt from `django.db.models.fields.files`:

```
def open(self, mode='rb'):
    self._require_file()
    self.file.open(mode)
# open() doesn't alter the file's contents, but it does reset the pointer
open.alters_data = True
```

So, in the case of a `FileField`, `open` reopens the file using the specified mode. Then, once you call `open`, you can continue to use methods like `read` using the newly applied mode.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly but `django.db.models.fields.files` does not utilize `file.storage.exists()` method so I had to implement my own small function to have cross-storage compatible check for actual physical file existence:

```
# Check whether actual file of FileField exists (is not deleted / moved out).
def file_exists(obj):
    return obj.storage.exists(obj.name)
```