# Django FieldFile cannot write on the first open

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write to a FieldFile of an instance of a model:

```
class SourceFile(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField('File Name', max_length = 100, unique=True)
    import_time = models.DateTimeField('Import Time', auto_now_add = True)
    local_link = models.FileField(upload_to="ozio/uploaded_files/%Y")
```

Having no problem when I create the file with:

```
source_file = SourceFile.objects.create(file_name = source_file_name)
source_file.local_link.save(source_file.file_name, ContentFile('LINE1'))
```

However when I tried to append new lines:

```
source_file.local_link.open('a')  # Open as append mode
source_file.local_link.write('LINE2')
```

It complains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
io.UnsupportedOperation: write
```

When close it and reopen, everything looks ok. Grateful for any suggestion.

```
>>> source_file, created = SourceFile.objects.get_or_create(file_name = 'Manual.2014.Q2.csv')
>>> source_file.local_link
<FieldFile: ozio/uploaded_files/2014/Manual.2014.Q2.csv>
>>> source_file.local_link.open('a')
>>> source_file.local_link.write('LINE2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
io.UnsupportedOperation: write
>>> source_file.local_link.close()
>>> source_file.local_link.open('a')
>>> source_file.local_link.write('LINE2')
5
>>> source_file.local_link.close()
>>> source_file, created = SourceFile.objects.get_or_create(file_name = 'Manual.2014.Q2.csv')
>>> source_file.local_link.open('a')
>>> source_file.local_link.close()
>>> source_file.local_link.open('a')
>>> source_file.local_link.write('LINE3')
5
>>> source_file.local_link.close()
>>>
```

Comment: formatting of the class (line 2 .. 4) seems broken.

Comment: thanks, prob with copy and paste. updated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20643607/892327 is relevant. Underlying issue is that FieldFile.open() doesn't do what the docs say it does.